# change my list of objects into dictionary key list objects using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I am generating list of objects now I need to change that list of objects with specific id inner that contains that specific id objects data by using dictionary.

This is my complete code.

```
m_Query = m_Query + " LEFT JOIN LIBRARY lib5 ON lib5.LIBRARY_ID = comm.STATUS2";
if (comObj.ProductsID != "" || comObj.ProductsID != null)
{
    m_Query = m_Query + " where prod1.PRODUCT_ID in ";
    string allproducts = string.Empty;
    allproducts = comObj.ProductsID;
    m_Query = m_Query + " ("+ allproducts + ") order by prod1.PRODUCT_ID desc";
}

DataSet dsPck = new DataSet();
dsPck = conn.GetDataSet(m_Query, CommandType.Text, ConnectionState.Open);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dsPck.Tables[0];

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CommitmentReport Info = new CommitmentReport();
        Info.PRODUCT_ID = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
        Info.ProductName = dt.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString();
        Info.COMMITMENT_ID = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["COMMITMENT_ID"].ToString());
        Info.ReferenceNo = dt.Rows[i]["ReferenceNo"].ToString();
        Info.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["CreatedDate"].ToString());
        Info.Numbers = dt.Rows[i]["Numbers"].ToString();
        Info.Catalogue = dt.Rows[i]["Catalogue"].ToString();
        Info.Specification = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["Specification"].ToString());
        Info.Type = dt.Rows[i]["Type"].ToString();
        Info.SubmissionType = dt.Rows[i]["SubmissionType"].ToString();
        Info.ApprovalStatus = dt.Rows[i]["ApprovalStatus"].ToString();
        Info.Country = dt.Rows[i]["Country"].ToString();
        Info.Status = dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
        //  Info.Count = x;
        commLst.Add(Info);
    }
}
```

I am returning list of objects but now I need to change every specific key(PID) inner that contains related  objects.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly you are looking for? Sample input/ output?

Comment: need to change my list of objects into dictionary key list

Comment: input is multiple PIDs.  need output list is:    PID1: related objects. PID2: related objects etc

Comment: so you are saying there are items with same `PRODUCT_ID`, and you want to group them by their `PRODUCT_ID`?

Comment: yes.  correct . i need output is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question what I understand is `CommObj` is a `List<ComRep>` and you want to get the item to a dictionary that matches the specific key. if so you can try the following

```
string ProductID = "PID1";
var selectedProduct = CommObj.Where(x=> x.ProductID == ProductID)
                             .ToDictionary(y=> y.ProductID, y=> y); 
var allProducts = CommObj.ToDictionary(y=> y.ProductID, y=> y);  // all items to dictionary
```

Or you can try this, if you need a Dictionary instead for this list.

```
Dictionary<string,ComRep> ComRepDict = new Dictionary<string,ComRep>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(!ComRepDict.ContainsKey(dt.Rows[i]["PID"].ToString())
    {
      ComRepDict.Add( dt.Rows[i]["PID"].ToString(), new ComRep(){
                      PID = dt.Rows[i]["PID"].ToString();
                      PName = dt.Rows[i]["PName"].ToString();
                      PDesc = dt.Rows[i]["PDesc"].ToString();
                      commitmentid = dt.Rows[i]["commitmentid"].ToString();
                      country = dt.Rows[i]["country"].ToString();
                      status = dt.Rows[i]["status"].ToString();
                     Count = x;
                   });
}
```

**Updates :**

```
 var groupedProducts = CommObj.GroupBy(x=> x.ProductID)
                              .ToDictionary(y=> y.Key, y=> y.ToList());
```

return `groupedProducts`, change the return type as `Dictionary<string,List<ComRep>>`

Comment: please see my changed code. will u please try to change my code and return grouped objects

Comment: Still i don't get your actual requirement. have you tried with `Dictionary<string,ComRep>` and return `ComRepDict `  change the return type of the method to `Dictionary<string,ComRep>`

Comment: i have multiple productids. i need to return that grouped objects. like ProductID1 : objects is productID1 related. productID2 :  objects is productID2 related.  i need to return like that. grouping that related productsid

Comment: @Ayyappa: See the **Updates** in my post

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<long, System.Collections.Generic.List
<EX_BusinessLayer.Models.CommitmentReport>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EX_BusinessLayer.Models.CommitmentReport>'
 EX_BusinessLayer D:\EX\Code\EX_BusinessLayer\Actions\CommitmentReportActions.cs

Comment: PRODUCT_ID is int64 not string.

Comment: Make changes as per that

Comment: i already changed. but not to convert var groupedproduct to list. it shows above error

Comment: i got the actual data in groupedproducts. thanks for helping thta. now how to return grouped products if i return grouped products it shows above error. please solve this.

Comment: how to convert groupedProducts to list.

Answer (score 1):

Way to go is this if you want to have a dictionary instead of list:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<ComRep>>();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ComRep Info = new ComRep();
        ....
        /// Your object initialization here

        if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(Info.PID))
            dictionary.Add(Info.PID, new List<ComRep>{ Info });
        else
            dictionary[Info.PID].Add(Info);
    }
}

return dictionary;
```

Comment: will u please try to change my code and return grouped objects

Comment: on return dictionary shows error.  dictionary is declared but never used.

Comment: need to return grouped list

Comment: The only mistake in my code was the `return` keyword, I mistyped it. Now it's fixed. Tried, working.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<long, System.Collections.Generic.List <EX_BusinessLayer.Models.CommitmentReport>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EX_BusinessLayer.Models.Com‌​mitmentReport>' EX_BusinessLayer D:\EX\Code\EX_BusinessLayer\Actions\Commit‌​mentReportActions.cs

Comment: show your methods signature please. Your return type is not same as what you want.

Comment: and where that `long` came from? You've mixed the reality and the simplified question, and not able to distinguish them.

Comment: i replaced int64 instead of string because productid is int64. if i use string it shows error, so replaced that to int64

Comment: alright. Listen here. We are willing to return a `Dictionary<long, List<CommitmentReport>`. The error message provided says, the return type of your method is actually `List<CommitmentReport>`. Hence you must change it from list to dictionary as well, since we are actually returning dictionary.

Comment: i got the data in dictionary. thanks for helping that now  how to convert var dictionary to list. if i tried it shows above error.

Comment: How are you planning to have groups in a plain list?

Comment: Your overall design has major conflictions with your mind. Fix your mind. Then recheck the answers.

Comment: this code i am writing in list return method. i need to return list format only bcz if i change return type it effects. so need to return list